# Codeigniter callback with model name

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a file named form_validation.php in application/config and it contains the statements:

```
<?php
$config=array(
'user_add'=>array(
array
(
'field'=>'username',
'label'=>'Username',
'rules'=>'trim|xss_clean|required|callback_user_model->is_unique[username]'
),

......                      )
);
?>
```

and here i want to create a call back to a function named `is_unique()` in the model named user_model.Is it possible? and I hav read the article in http://codeigniter.com/wiki/MY_Validation_-_Callbacks_into_Models/.

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you're asking here? Can you give us a bit more information.

Comment: You post got cut off, please fix.

Comment: @Madmartin: I updated my missing portion.

Comment: You need to clarify your post. What are you trying to do? What did you try? What was the expected output? What was the actual output you got?

Answer (score 0):

please check manual of calling custom callback on validation

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/MY_Validation_-_Callbacks_into_Models/

Comment: i checked that manual already. But in that there is no database checking. So I am confused in doing that.